# Multivariable integral, use of Dirac Delta and Heaviside Theta

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, dirac-delta, step-function

$\newcommand{\diff}{\operatorname{d}}$
$\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\frac{\diff #1}{\diff #2}}$
$\newcommand{\pderiv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$
I have the following integral
$$\omega(E) = \int\frac{\diff\vec{q}\diff\vec{p}}{h^2}\delta(E - H(\vec{q}, \vec{p}))$$
where $\vec{p}, \vec{q}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $\vec{q} = (x, y)$ satisfy the constrain  $-L/2 \leq x, y, \leq L/2$ and $H(\vec{q}, \vec{p})$ is the function
\begin{align}
H(\vec{q}, \vec{p}) = H(\vec{q}, x) = \frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m} + 2A|x| &&\text{with}\quad A> 0
\end{align}
Now this is a part of en exercise and it has the following solution

> \begin{align}    \omega(E) &=
>  \frac{L}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\pderiv{}{E}\int\diff{\vec{p}}\
>  \Theta\left(E - \frac{p^2}{2m} - 2A|x|\right) = \tag{sol1.1}\label{sol1.1}\\    &=
>  \frac{L}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\ 2\pi m\pderiv{}{E}(E -
>  2A|x|)\Theta\left(E - 2A|x|\right) = \tag{sol1.2}\label{sol1.2}\\     &= \frac{2\pi
>  mL}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\ \Theta\left(E - 2A|x|\right) = \tag{sol1.3}\\
>    &= \begin{cases}\frac{2\pi
>  mL}{Ah^2}E & \text{if } E \leq AL\\ \frac{2\pi
>  mL^2}{h^2} & \text{if } E > AL\end{cases} \tag{sol1.4}
>  \end{align}
>   where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside Theta step function and it is used the fact that $\delta(x) = \deriv{}{x}\Theta(x)$.

Now I tried another way to the solution by using the property of the Dirac Delta 
$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_i \frac{\delta(x - x_i}{|f'(x_i)|}$$
where $x_i$ are the simple zeros of the function.

> ***My way***:
>   \begin{align}    \omega(E) &=
>  \frac{L}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\int\diff{\vec{p}}\
>  \delta\left(E - \frac{p^2}{2m} - 2A|x|\right) =\\    &=
>  \frac{L}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\ \int_0^{2\pi}\diff\phi\int_0^{\infty}\diff{p}\ p\ \delta\left(\tilde{E} - \frac{p^2}{2m}\right) = \\    &= \frac{2\pi L}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\ \int_0^{\infty}\diff{p}\ p\ \frac{\delta\left(p-\sqrt{2m\tilde{E}}\right)}{\sqrt{2m\tilde{E}}/m} = \\    &= \frac{2\pi mL}{h^2}\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\diff{x}\frac{\sqrt{2m\tilde{E}}}{\sqrt{2m\tilde{E}}} = \frac{2\pi mL^2}{h^2}
>  \end{align}

Clearly I miss a Theta in the last steps, because the two solutions are not the same. 
Now I have some doubts about these proceedings, which are the following

1. How did he integrate the Heaviside function in the first passage \eqref{sol1.1}-\eqref{sol1.2}, so that the integral gives $$(E - 2A|x|)\Theta\left(E - 2A|x|\right)?$$
2. Why did my solution differed from the one proposed, where am I going wrong?
3. Hoping that I'm not putting too much staff together, how do you recommend to proceed with multivariable integrals involving delta and theta when inside them there's a functional expression?

**EDIT:**
Since the problem is physical (from statistical mechanics), I'm now noticing that probably the theta is there for having non-negative roots of $p^2$... could it be right?

Comment: The dirac delta property that you wrote out should have $|f \;'(x_i)|$ in the denominator. I don't know if this changes anything or if it was a simple typo

Comment: Yeah, just a typo, thanks anyway!

Comment: Are the solutions given by the exercise correct? The two solutions seem to have different units

Comment: I miss an $L^2$, and the constant $A$ is such that everything must be okay.